# Using regex backreference value as numeric value in regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I've got a string that has variable length sections. The length of the section precedes the content of that section. So for example, in the string:

```
13JOHNSON,STEVE
```

The first 2 characters define the content length (13), followed by the actual content. I'd like to be able to parse this using named capture groups with a backreference, but I'm not sure it is possible. I was hoping this would work:

```
(?<length>\d{2})(?<name>.{\k<length>})
```

But it doesn't. Seems like the backreference isn't interpreted as a number. This works fine though:

```
(?<length>\d{2})(?<name>.{13})
```

Comment: Why not show a more complete example of the string? It sounds like you've decided a pattern is the right way to attack this problem, but based on this sample I would do it a lot differently. Regex have their place but they're not a universal hammer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that will not work of course. You need to recompile your regular expression after extracting the first number.

I would recommend you to use two different expressions:
the first one that extracts number, and the second one that extracts texts basing on the number extracted by the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

```
>> s = '13JOHNSON,STEVE'
=> "13JOHNSON,STEVE"
>> length = s[/^\d{2}/].to_i # s[0,2].to_i
=> 13
>> s[2,length]
=> "JOHNSON,STEVE"
```

Comment: This is the answer. Use the regex to extract the number, and then you don't need a regex any more.

Comment: This can be simplified to `s[/^(\d{2})/]; s[2, $1.to_i]  # => "JOHNSON,STEVE"` It will break if there are any characters preceding the length characters or there are multiple length+name combinations in a string, as the OP said.

Answer (score 1):

This really seems like you're going after this the hard way. I suspect the sample string is not as simple as you said, based on:

> I've got a string that has variable length sections. The length of the section precedes the content of that section.

Instead I'd use something like:

```
str = "13JOHNSON,STEVE 08Blow,Joe 10Smith,John" 
str.scan(/\d{2}(\S+)/).flatten # => ["JOHNSON,STEVE", "Blow,Joe", "Smith,John"]
```

If the string can be split accurately, then there's this:

```
str.split.map{ |s| s[2..-1] }  # => ["JOHNSON,STEVE", "Blow,Joe", "Smith,John"]
```

If you only have length bytes followed by strings, with nothing between them something like this works:

```
offset = 0
str.delete!(' ') # => "13JOHNSON,STEVE08Blow,Joe10Smith,John"
str.scan(/\d+/).map{ |l| s = str[offset + 2, l.to_i]; offset += 2 + l.to_i ; s } 
# => ["JOHNSON,STEVE", "Blow,Joe", "Smith,John"]
```

---

> won't work if the names have digits in them – tihom

```
str = "13JOHNSON,STEVE 08Blow,Joe 10Smith,John 1012345,7890" 
str.scan(/\d{2}(\S+)/).flatten # => ["JOHNSON,STEVE", "Blow,Joe", "Smith,John", "12345,7890"]
str.split.map{ |s| s[2..-1] }  # => ["JOHNSON,STEVE", "Blow,Joe", "Smith,John", "12345,7890"]
```

With a a minor change, and minor addition it'll continue to work correctly with strings not containing delimiters:

```
str.delete!(' ') # => "13JOHNSON,STEVE08Blow,Joe10Smith,John1012345,7890"

offset = 0
str.scan(/\d{2}/).map{ |l| s = str[offset + 2, l.to_i]; offset += 2 + l.to_i ; s }.compact 
# => ["JOHNSON,STEVE", "Blow,Joe", "Smith,John", "12345,7890"]
```

`\d{2}` grabs the numerics in groups of two. For the names where the numeric is a leading length value of two characters, which is according to the OPs sample, the correct thing happens. For a solid numeric "name" several false-positives are returned, which would return `nil` values. `compact` cleans those out.

Comment: won't work if the names have digits in them

Comment: Thanks for the responses Tin Man, you are correct that the string is more complicated than the snippet I use as an example. I just wanted to know if something like this was possible in regex before I fallback to more conventional methods.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
a = '13JOHNSON,STEVE'

puts a.match /(?<length>\d{2})(?<name>(.*),(.*))/
```